# R dplyr chaining group by into function

Tags: r, filtering, dplyr, signal-processing

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
  time id trialNum trialType        accX     gravX
1    1  6        7       low -0.38876217 10.185266
2    2  1        6       low  0.68254705 10.741545
3    3  3       15      high -0.21906854  9.466929
4    4  2       15      none -0.03370001  9.490829
5    5  4        1      high  0.16511542 10.986796
6    6  9        2      none -0.10441621  9.915561
```

You can generate something similar using this:

```
testDF <- data.frame(time = 1:50,
                     id = sample(1:10, size=50, replace=T),
                     trialNum = sample(1:15, size = 50, replace=T),
                     trialType = sample(c("none", "low", "high"),
                                        size = 50, replace=T),
                     accX = sin(seq(1,50,1)),
                     gravX = 0.1)
```

And a function to calculate the average time between peaks in a filtered signal (returning mean time, and variance of the time differences):

```
library(dplyr)
library(signal)
library(quantmod)

calcStepTime <- function(df){
  bf <- butter(1, c(0.03,0.05), type="pass")
  filtered <- filtfilt(bf, df$accX - df$gravX)

  peaks            <- findPeaks(filtered)
  peakValue        <- filtered[peaks]
  peakTime         <- df$time[peaks]

  timeDifferences  <- diff(peakTime)
  meanStepTime     <- mean(timeDifferences)
  varianceStepTime <- var(timeDifferences)

  return(c(meanStepTime, varianceStepTime))
}
```

What I'm trying to do apply this function to each combination of `id`, `trialNum`, and `trialType` using `groupby`:

```
tempTrial <-
    group_by(testDF, id, trialNum, trialType) %>%
    summarise(meanTime = calcStepTime(.)[1],
              varianceTime= calcStepTime(.)[2])
```

The problem is that in the output dataframe (`tempTrial`) every row of `meanTime` and `varianceTime` is identical

In this toy dataset, sometimes the columns all show `NA` (this doesnt happen in my actual dataset)

Am I doing something incorrectly to cause each row to be identical for the 2 columns? It should be taking each combination of `id`, `trialNum` and `trialType`, and calculating peak times for each of those separately. However, it seems its only storing a single value for each combination?

Comment: I am getting an error. `Error: could not find function "butter"` Please provide library names.

Comment: Here, `findPeaks(filtered)` returning `numeric(0)`

Comment: You're grouping a relatively small dataframe by several variables, meaning your "grouped" dataframe may be the same size (or close to it) as your original dataframe.  If so, each group is one row long, and it's not possible to find a peak in a single row.

Comment: I've adjusted my testDF code above so it no longer generates NAs by generating a sine wave instead. This should fix the `numeric(0)` issue. I know the test data is small, but my actual data is about 100,000 rows so there must be an issue elsewhere because I get the same number in every row regardless of sample size

Comment: the problem with small groups is secondary to the problem of the usage of `.` in summarise. While it is worth fixing the small groups or defensively coding so that it no longer generates `NA`'s or `NaN`'s, the problem is not going to be solved unless you realise that the combination of `summarise` and `.` is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get right now is the result of `calcStepTime` applied on the whole (ungrouped) data frame for each group.

Try rewriting the function such that it depends on the variables, but not on the data frame.

```
alcStepTime <- function(var1, var2, var3){
  bf <- butter(1, c(0.03,0.05), type="pass")
  filtered <- filtfilt(bf, var1 - var2)

  peaks <- findPeaks(filtered)
  peakValue <- filtered[peaks]
  peakTime <- var3[peaks]

  timeDifferences <- diff(peakTime)

  meanStepTime <- mean(timeDifferences)

  varianceStepTime <- var(timeDifferences)

  return(c(meanStepTime, varianceStepTime))
}



testDF %>% group_by(testDF, id, trialNum, trialType) %>%
 summarise(meanTime = calcStepTime( accX, gravX, time)[1], 
        varianceTime= calcStepTime(accX, gravX, time)[2])
```

It gives the right result if you just pipe the testDF data frame into it. It breaks for the grouped DF but I can't find if that's because the function is not defined for the subsets or if it's a problem with the function.

let me know if it works for the full data

Answer (score 2):

The chain is working properly in the sense that `.` refers to the grouped data frame `group_by(testDF, id, trialNum, trialType)`. Since your defined function has no way of using the group information in `.`, the results are what you see (i.e. the function applied to the whole data frame).

So your problem here is the incorrect use of `summarise`. Latrunculia's answer shows you that the proper way to use `summarise` in the way you expect is to apply the function to combinations of columns in your data frame, in which case the function applies by group in each variable.

`dplyr` has a `do` function for applications where you wish to apply a function to the data frame subset implied by `group_by`. Simply replace your `summarise` with `do`:

```
tempTrial <- group_by(testDF, id, trialNum, trialType) %>% do(meanTime = calcStepTime(.)[1], varianceTime= calcStepTime(.)[2])
```

The documentation for `do` is not terribly clear, but [this post](http://stat545.com/block023_dplyr-do.html#meet-do) describes the application very well.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by yourself and Latrunculia, `calcStepTime` is very likely to return NaN/NA on the 50 observation datasets. This occurs when either no peak or a single peak was found within a group of observations. You may want to defend against this in your analysis code. I used this for testing:

```
testDF <- data.frame(time = 1:200, 
                 id = sample(1:2, size=200, replace=T), 
                 trialNum = sample(1:1, size = 200, replace=T), 
                 trialType = sample(c("low"), size = 200, replace=T), 
                 accX = sin(seq(1,200,1)), 
                 gravX = 0.1)
```

If you change the return type of your function of `data_frame` (tibble), like so:

```
calcStepTime <- function(df){
  bf <- butter(1, c(0.03,0.05), type="pass")
  filtered <- filtfilt(bf, df$accX - df$gravX)

  peaks <- findPeaks(filtered)
  peakValue <- filtered[peaks]
  peakTime <- df$time[peaks]

  timeDifferences <- diff(peakTime)

  meanStepTime <- mean(timeDifferences)

  varianceStepTime <- var(timeDifferences)

  return (data_frame("meanStepTime" = meanStepTime, 
                     "varianceStepTime" = varianceStepTime))
}
```

Then you can take advantage of `purrr::by_slice()` for a fairly elegant solution:

```
library(purrr)
testDF %>%
group_by(id, trialNum, trialType) %>%
by_slice(calcStepTime, .collate="cols")
```

I got this from my test sample:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
     id trialNum trialType meanStepTime1 varianceStepTime1
    <int>    <int>    <fctr>         <dbl>             <dbl>
1     1        1       low         42.75          802.2500
2     2        1       low         39.75          616.9167
```

Note that `.collate="cols"` is the important argument that tells `by_slice()` to create the named columns for the results in the output. I'm a little curious myself as to why the "1" has been appended to the names we set in the data_frame returned by your function.